# Show that $\widehat{f}(n)$ is zero for odd $n$

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, fourier-series

The following problem is from Stein´s Introduction to Fourier analysis:

Suppose that $f(\theta + \pi)=f(\theta)$ for all $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ Show that $\widehat{f}(n)$ is zero for odd $n$.

My attempt:

$$\widehat{f}(n)= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi}f(\theta)e^{-in \theta}d\theta= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\pi}^{3 \pi}f(\theta+ \pi)e^{-in (\theta+ \pi)}d\theta = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{ \pi}f(\theta)e^{-in (\theta+ \pi)}d\theta $$ $$= \frac{1}{2 \pi}[ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(\theta)cos(n (\theta + \pi)) d\theta +i \int_{-\pi}^{ \pi}f(\theta)sin(n(\theta + \pi))d\theta ] $$ $$= -\frac{1}{2 \pi}[ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(\theta)cos(n (\theta )) d\theta +i \int_{-\pi}^{ \pi}f(\theta)sin(n(\theta ))d\theta ]=0 $$

only for odd n

well the thing is that I am not sure about my last step, can you help me to fix the proof or tell me if I am right, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Do you know that $f(\theta)$ is $2\pi$-periodic?

Comment: Yes is a Riemman integrable and 2$\pi$-periodic function :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to switch to $\cos$ and $\sin$. In the first line:

$$\begin{align}
\widehat{f}(n) &= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{0}^{2 \pi}f(\theta)e^{-in \theta}d\theta \\ &= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\pi}^{3 \pi}f(\theta+ \pi)e^{-in (\theta+ \pi)}d\theta \\ &= \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{ \pi}f(\theta)e^{-in \theta}e^{n\pi}d\theta \\
& = -\widehat{f}(n) \tag{since $e^{n\pi}=-1$ for odd $n$}
\end{align}$$

So $\widehat{f}(n)=0$

Comment: yes, that is right, thanks a lot, these completes the proof

Answer (score 1):

$\hat{f}(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(\theta)e^{-in\theta}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi} f(\theta)e^{-in\theta}+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} f(\theta)e^{-in\theta}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi} f(\theta)e^{-in\theta}+\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi} f(\theta)e^{-i(n+\pi)\theta}=0$

Change the variable of the second term.(Happens in the third equality)

Comment: Thanks a lot :), but can you explain your last part please (the change of variables)

Comment: $e^{-i(n+\pi)\theta}=-e^{-in\theta}$, sorry, I don't explain clearly, that change of variables happens in the third equality.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot :) but  the theta should be in the exponent right?

Comment: Yes, I correct that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help  :) I realy apprecite it